# NullPointer Exception ContextWrapper

Tags: android, achartengine

I am attempting to draw a Pie Graph using AChartEngine Library. I have no problem with this as I had already drew a graph on another Activity. Now I need to draw another graph, but I am getting a Nullpointer Exception on the ContextWrapper. This is what Logcat says :

```
06-20 17:09:46.391: W/System.err(14261): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 17:09:46.391: W/System.err(14261): at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
```

This is the line of code that causes the error:

```
PieGraph pie = new PieGraph();
View timesheetsPage = pie.getView(MainActivity.this , values, colors, jobDescriptions, totalTimes);
```

As you can see, I use `MainActivity.this` as my context, even if I use getApplicationContext() I get the same error. All the other parameters I know for sure are not null.

This code worked perfectly on a graph in another Activity, so I doubt its an AChartEngine Library problem.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you give us the full stack trace, so we can see what line in your code actually causes this to happen. Can you give line numbers in the source code?

Comment: `NullpointerException` is usually easy to debug, are you sure that "pie" instance is not null? What about other parameters? Double check their nullness in debug mode.